# How to maximize window in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, window, maximize

This SHOULD be a very simple question but after lots of searching there seems to be no working example anywhere.
I just want my XNA window to start off maximized.
I know how to set the width and height of the window, but that's not quite the same.
I also need to do this without going full screen. I just want a normal maximized window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Cyral has the closest answer so far, but it's still not quite what you want.  To maximize a Windows Form, you use the WindowState property:

```
var form = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: This looks great but how can I access the Form class in XNA? If I try to reference it with System.Windows.Form it isn't found. And if I try to add "using System.Windows" at the top it is also not found.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly in your XNA project, and probably `System.Drawing.dll` as well.

Comment: Much thanks I am just now learning how to add in references like that, but it works fine now.

Comment: Also add like ...(System.Windows.Forms.Form)System.Windows.Form.FromHa.... etc so you dont get ambiguities

Answer (score 5):

Set the `IsFullScreen` property of the graphics device manager to true.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195024(v=xnagamestudio.10).aspx

```
    //from the above msdn sample
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager( this );
    content = new ContentManager( Services );

    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
    graphics.PreferMultiSampling = false;
    graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.isfullscreen(v=xnagamestudio.10).aspx

Comment: You may also need to call `graphics.ApplyChanges();`

Comment: @JohnMcDonald Hm maybe, I don't have xna on this machine to check.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I don't want to be in fullscreen. I still need the minimized/maximize/close buttons to be visible.

Comment: @Frobot Uh yeah that's an important detail.

Comment: @Frobot An XNA window is still just a window. Call the normal windows API to maximize it.

Comment: Usually I would use this.WindowState which I don't have access to in XNA

Answer (score 2):

You can add a reference to System.Windows.Forms and System.Drawing (However, You will need to type the namespaces out, Because of ambiguities)

Use the following code after base.Initialize

```
Form form = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
form.Location = Point(0, 0);
form.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have covered the step of maximizing automatically, but to enable the actual maximize button so the user can do it when desired, do this in the Game constructor:

```
Window.AllowUserResizing = true;
```

Depending on how you want the game to behave when resizing begins and ends, perhaps pause the game, you may need to handle some of these events.

```
    Form form = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
    form.ResizeBegin += new EventHandler(form_ResizeBegin);
    form.ResizeEnd += new EventHandler(form_ResizeEnd);
    form.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(form_LocationChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
DisplayMode displayMode = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode;
this._graphics.PreferredBackBufferFormat = displayMode.Format;
this._graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = (int)(displayMode.Width);
this._graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = (int)(displayMode.Height);
```

**Sort of** works for me but not quite, you'll understand once you try. I mean, it's not perfect and I'm sure there's a better way but for prototyping this should work - or maybe with some tweaking you could get what you need.