# C# Launch a game maximized

Tags: c#, maximize

I'm using C# visual studio with XNA and I would like to launch my game in maximized instead of fullscreen, and nothing found on google has worked yet...

I tried using:

```
Form form = (Form)Control.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

But even with the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and `System.Drawing.dll` references, it doesn't work, tells me that Form doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the code you have tried so far, so we can help you?

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you put this code?

Have you set WindowState before InitializeComponent(), like this?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public Form() //Constructor
{
    var form = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: I put it in Initialize(), at the beginning. When I type your code, VS tells me that `WindowState`, `FormWindowState.Maximized` and `InitializeComponent()` doesn't exist in the current context. I am not sure I put the references in the right place, is it in "Namespace/References" or "NamespaceContent/References"?

Comment: Sorry, code updated. Was your original code in the form constructor?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786640/how-to-maximize-window-in-xna

Comment: Ah, I just had to add `System.Windows.Forms.` before all the `Form`. That solves the problem! Thanks very much!

Comment: Great! :-) I'll update my answer in case it helps someone else.